# simulation data flow diagram in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, dataflow-diagram, dfd

I'm using EA 16.1 TRIAL and created it from a pattern that provides an example data flow model. When I started to simulate this, only Process1 works and Simulation Ended is displayed immediately. Is it impossible to simulate the data flow diagram?
[image]

Comment: I forgot that EA has this rather un-fitting DFD. Anyhow, I don't think they allow simulation. That's for BPMN and activities only (not sure about states, but I never used these toys in EA anyway - for good reason).